# How can I multiply (double) my input frequency without distorting my waveform?

Tags: filter, frequency, signal

I'm looking to double my input frequency in my circuit, but it's important that the signal stays the same shape as much as possible. I'm working with low sine wave frequency's.

Edit: Sorry it took so long to get back. I am working with audio signals.

Comment: @user2143-Can you provide the information about the circuit which your talking here.just i'm asking its circuit diagram.What type of signal you want to increase,Audio signal video signal like that.Give us some more information about it

Comment: Are digital techniques acceptable?

Comment: @Dr X: I think digital techniques are *necessary*. I don't believe this can be done with only analogue techniques.

Comment: @Federico, that was my feeling too. Unless you can somehow decompose the signal and remodulate it, but there's not nearly enough information in the question to infer that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume that you want the converted signal in the same time as the original. That means that you will have to output every period twice at the higher frequency.
Example: suppose the original signal is 100Hz, then you have 1 period in 10ms. Doubling to 200Hz will give you one period in 5ms, so you'll have to output that twice in succession to fill the original 10ms.
This is easy if you do it digitally: convert to digital using an ADC, store samples in an buffer array, and read every other sample (for instance only the even samples) at the same rate and output that to a DAC, and do this twice per period of the signal. The buffer is needed because reading you go through the data twice as fast as writing; if you don't have the buffer you would need to read data in the future.
The problem is determining the period. The signal should have a well-defined repetition rate to find the period over which you'll sample. You'll need a DSP to do this.

**edit**
From Olin's comment I guess I didn't make it clear that you have to adapt the buffer length to the current frequency. That's why you need the DSP to detect the frequency. This remains awkward business anyway if your signal isn't very repetitive, i.e. periods of a certain frequency occur only during one period.

Comment: why decimate? just replay at twice the rate?

Comment: @Jason - Is possible, of course, but my experience is that DSP systems usually use only a single sample clock, for both ADC and DAC.

Comment: This only doubles one of the frequencies, which is the dominant one causing the zero crossings.  If the input signal is just a single frequency then this will work, but the OP didn't say that.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to do what you describe in 'real time' unless you can fully describe what periodic aspects of the signal you're interested in.  For example, if "X" represents 10ms of a 1khz 0db sine wave, and "x" represents 10ms of a 1khz -6db sine wave, and the input signal repeats the following pattern "XxXxXxXxXXxx", what should be the output, if "Y" represents 5ms of 2khz 0db sine wave, and "y" represents 5ms of -6db sine wave?  Should it be "YyYyYyYyYYyyYyYyYyYyYYyy", or "YYyyYYyyYYyyYYyyYYYYyyyy", or "YyYyYyYyYyYyYyYyYYyyYYyy", or something else?

If your goal is to have something which sounds like the original signal, but up an octave, your best bet is probably to use DSP techniques to decompose the original signal into discrete frequency components and generate a new signal with the appropriate doubled components.  This will likely yield waveforms which "look" nothing like the originals, but which sound as they should.  Approaches which attempt to "cut and paste" snippets of waveforms will often yield wave shapes which look more like the originals, but which sound nothing like them.